# Independent and depentent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

\begin{matrix}
        3 & -6 & 6 \\
        2 & -2 & 6 \\
        2 & -2 & a \\
        -3 & 7 & -5 \\
        \end{matrix}

Determine all values of $a$ for which the following set of vectors is dependent or independent. You can select $always$, $'never$', '$a =$ ', or $'a ≠'$, then specify a value or comma-separated list of values.

After doing row operations i have gotten :
\begin{matrix}
        1 & -2 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & a/2 -5 \\
        \end{matrix}

I know that set of vectors are independent when all the columns have pivots. 
I am not sure how to answer the question. 
I would say that it is independent when $a/2 -5=0$ so $ a=10$ and dependent when $a≠10.$
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there was an error in the row reduction.  Here are the row reduction steps:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&-6&6\\
2&-2&6\\
2&-2&a\\
-3&7&-5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$\frac{1}{3}R_1\rightarrow R_1$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&2\\
2&-2&6\\
2&-2&a\\
-3&7&-5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$-2R_1+R_2\rightarrow R_2$, $-2R_1+R_3\rightarrow R_3$, and $3R_1+R_4\rightarrow R_4$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&2\\
0&2&2\\
0&2&a-4\\
0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$R_2\leftrightarrow R_4$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&2\\
0&1&1\\
0&2&a-4\\
0&2&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$-2R_2+R_3\rightarrow R_3$ and $-2R_2+R_4\rightarrow R_4$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&2\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&a-6\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is in row echelon form regardless of the value of $a$.  If $a$ is not $6$, then the last column has a pivot, and otherwise, the last column does not have a pivot.

Comment: thank yo very much. I was actully doing it now to see where i made the mistake

Answer (score 1):

A pivot is a leading nonzero entry after the matrix has been put in row echelon form.  For this matrix, when $a=10$, the matrix is already in row echelon form.  When $a\not=10$, you can use the third row to cancel out the $a/2-5$.

Now, circle your pivots.  They are the leading nonzero entries.  You should get three pivots.  Look at the columns that these pivots are in, and you're done.

Comment: @MichealBurr the matrix is always independent and never dependent, is that correct.

Comment: A matrix is not independent or dependent.  The *columns* of the matrix can be independent or dependent.  Yes, the columns are always independent.

Comment: I have entered that answer and it is incorrect. It said that set is dependent when a=6 and independent when a is not 6.

Comment: Check your row reduction.  It is incorrect.  I did not check your row reduction, only your interpretation of the final answer.